# Why does _.extend make a shallow copy?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I've looked through the documentation and source code, and it appears that underscore's extend method `_.extend` makes a shallow copy. One of the collaborators also said that the extend method does a shallow copy of the object "intentionally" [here](https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/issues/1246).

Now my question is : Why was it made that way ? Could you please provide me with some scenarios or use cases where this shallow copy would be better?

I tried to look for some answers and I couldn't find much about this except that "it's a good thing".

Answer (score 2):

Deep copies or object clones are very computational expensive. `_.extend` is essentially just an alias for `_.assignIn(object, [sources])` which does pretty much the same as `_.assign` but iterates over own and inherited source properties. The native ES6 `Object.assign` does not iterate over inherited source properties.

Taking the example from lodash's documentation on `assignIn`, `Object.assign` would give you the following output:

```
function Foo() {
  this.a = 1;
}

function Bar() {
  this.c = 3;
}

Foo.prototype.b = 2;
Bar.prototype.d = 4;

console.log(Object.assign({ 'a': 0 }, new Foo, new Bar));
// { a: 1, c: 3 }
```

Whereas `_assignIn` or `_.extend` gives you

```
// { 'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4 }
```

As you can see, also inherited source properties (set via the prototype), that is `b` and `d`, were also iterated.

If you want to deeply clone an object, you can use `_.cloneDeep(value)`. But keep in mind that such deep clone is very **computational expensive** compared to a shallow copy.